# How to set some variable to some value when option is present

Tags: bash

I am not good at Bash scripting, and trying to learn more. Let me introduce my question with code:

```
#!/bin/bash
version_num=
isWindows=
MSVC_VER=
VERBOSE=
while getopts “hw:v:m:V” OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         w)
             isWindows=$OPTARG
             ;;
         v)
             version_num=$OPTARG
             ;;
         m)
             MSVC_VER=$OPTARG
             ;;
         V)
             VERBOSE=1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done
```

For space, usage function is removed.

My questions are:

**First question**:

currently, if I use this script, I have to feed parameter values after each option, for example:

```
 `bash test_bash.sh -v 4.2.2.0 -m 10.0 -w 1`
```

However, assuming that I only need to see whether `-w` is present, then set some variable value. I don't want to provide `-w 1` since `1` is just a flag to do something. I would like the script to work like:

```
 bash test_bash.sh -w -v 4.2.2.0 -m 10.0
```

How can I achieve this? I would like to do something like `rm -r -f`, which can have multiple options and does not require that each option is followed by some value.

**Second question**:

if I remove

```
V)
   VERBOSE=1 
   ;;
```

and `:V` from the `while` line as well as `VERBOSE=`, this script does not work anymore. Is it because `:V` is required?

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a `:` after a letter in the `getopts` parameter indicates whether it takes a parameter after it or not.  So change to:

```
while getopts “hwv:m:V” OPTION
```

Removeing `:V` from the script breaks it because the `:` is for the `m` option that comes before it, not the `V` option that comes after. When you remove that `:`, it means that `m` no longer takes a parameter, but you need that.